# Why does pylint not detect missing member functions (E1103) in lists?

Tags: python, pylint

When running pylint on a particular piece of code, I get false negatives for missing functions if the variables have been added to lists with .append() or += [var].  Is there any way to avoid having pylint lose the variable type here?  (pylint 0.27.0, python 2.7.2)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from foo.lib.machine import Machine
lh = Machine('localhost')

lh.is_reachable()      #Pylint catches this
machines = [lh]
m2 = []
m2.append(lh)
m3 = []
m3 += [lh]
for m in machines:
    m.is_reachable()   #Pylint catches this
for m in m2:
    m.is_reachable()   #Pylint MISSES this
for m in m3:
    m.is_reachable()   #Pylint MISSES this
```

```
$ pylint -i y -E pylintcheck
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module pylintcheck
E1101:  6,0: Instance of 'Machine' has no 'is_reachable' member
E1101: 13,4: Instance of 'Machine' has no 'is_reachable' member
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ned is right. For the record, when pylint tries to know what's inside a e.g. list, it only considers statements that *defines* this list, not all accesses to it. That explains why in your sample case, it detects correctly what's in `machines` but not in `m2` or `m3` (considered empty).

Comment: Thanks; I hadn't made the distinction between definition and access, which seems to be the key in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Python is dynamically typed, and analysis tools have a hard time understanding everything that might happen.  Looks like you've reached the end of what pylint understands.

Comment: Totally agree. Now, as always, this is Free Software, so patches are welcome :-)